# mosquitto-clients and broker running on SSL

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I've managed to setup a broker using SSL using Let's Encrypt certs.

I've tried testing a websockets client connecting to `wss://broker:9002/mqtt`, and it's working. I've also tried using `mqtt.js` command-line interface to subscribe to a topic on the broker `mqtts://broker:8883/mqtt` successfully.

However, I can't get `mosquitto_sub` and `mosquitto_pub` to work. 
I tried with,

```
$ mosquitto_sub -h www.my-host.com.ar -p 8883 -t hello -d --cafile fullchain.pem
Client mosqsub/21069-atlantis sending CONNECT
Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

where fullchain.pem is the same ca cert that's on the server.

The mosquitto.log's broker shows,

```
1456709201: OpenSSL Error: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
1456709201: OpenSSL Error: error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure
1456709201: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1456709206: New connection from <my-ip> on port 8883.
```

What could be happening? I didn't provide any cert for `mqtt.js` lib...

This is my broker conf (splitted in two files),

```
#################################
# /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf #
#################################
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

listener 1883

listener 8883
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-host.com.ar/fullchain.pem
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-host.com.ar/cert.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-host.com.ar/privkey.pem

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

#############################################
# /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/websockets_ssl.conf #
#############################################
listener 9002
protocol websockets
cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-host.com.ar/fullchain.pem
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-host.com.ar/cert.pem
keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-host.com.ar/privkey.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "--insecure" at the end of the mosquitto_sub and mosquitto_pub commands.  This allows the clients to bypass the check that matches the certificate hostname with the remote host name.  I've had to do this with some of the self-signed certs that I generated.

Here is the relevant comments from the "--help" for those commands:

```
--insecure : do not check that the server certificate hostname matches the remote
             hostname. Using this option means that you cannot be sure that the
             remote host is the server you wish to connect to and so is insecure.
             Do not use this option in a production environment.
```

Comment: `mosquitto_sub -h <broker-host> -p 8883 -t test --insecure -d` keeps trying to send CONNECT, while on the broker log says `routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol`

Comment: plus, I the broker is using Let's Encrypt certificates which should be valid